# Should I use a FORM element if I'm not submitting data? Proper (X)HTML markup

Tags: html, css, forms, xhtml, accessibility

In my web application I have a user profile page. That page has these elements on it:

```
Connect with Twitter
Connect with Facebook
Timezone Select
Language Select
```

The first two things pop up an OAuth window allowing the user to connect. The last two things are saved with AJAX.

When I'm doing up the page, how should I do the HTML? I think that all of the items should probably be <li> elements in a 'ul' element, opposed to separate 'div' or 'p' elements for each.

**But what container element should I use? I am debating between just using a 'div' and using a 'form' that has no action.**

I am collecting some data, that's the argument for a 'form' element, but the form is not actually going to be used - there will be no submit button. So that is the argument against it.

What would be the best practice for doing this? If you can provide a link to some supporting documentation that would be helpful, too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best practice is making the site work without Javascript, then adding Javascript / AJAX to it incrementally, as enhancements.

[Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) (Wikipedia)

> Progressive enhancement is a strategy
>   for web design that emphasizes
>   accessibility, semantic HTML markup,
>   and external stylesheet and scripting
>   technologies. Progressive enhancement
>   uses web technologies in a layered
>   fashion that allows everyone to access
>   the basic content and functionality of
>   a web page, using any browser or
>   Internet connection, while also
>   providing those with better bandwidth,
>   more advanced browser software or more
>   experience an enhanced version of the
>   page.

So yes, you should use a `form`.**

** if you care about progressive enhancement. As discussed in the comments for this answer, in your case, where you don't / can't care, it doesn't matter. Use whatever element you like best.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of progressive enhancement, I'm not asking about that. Some web apps require Javascript, like Facebook. Let's pretend that this is that type of web application. Besides progressive enhancement, do you have any argument in favor of a FORM that will not be used to submit data?

Comment: Progressive enhancement still applies to the timezone and language selectors, so the idea would be to have these be something like input selects inside of a form, so that users without Javascript can still use these controls and submit the form. If you're insistent on not having a non-Javascript version of these, then there's no reason to use a form element. In that case there would be no particular need for any container element, but if you want to use a `div`, that's fine.

Comment: Thanks. To clarify, the web application will require Javascript for all functionality - not just to connect to Facebook. Facebook is just an example of a mainstream web application that does not function *at all* without Javascript. Finally, my question is exactly your last sentence: Since there is no need for a particular container element, which one should I use? I think that using a FORM element where you collect information would still be more semantically correct than a DIV (division).

Comment: I'd say use form, but if you aren't going to make the site work without JS then it really doesn't matter.

Comment: Fair enough. I would argue against using form unless you're actually going to have a form that submits. To me, this is semantically and (I'd guess) visually not a form, so it shouldn't use the form tag. There may also be side effects if a user hits enter while a form subelement has focus, or in alternative browsers. Each of these clicky elements works independently, but if you want to semantically group them as a section of the page, use a div. At the end of the day, it's a subtle issue and there are no absolutes.

Comment: @joelhard, @cwd After reading joelhardi's recent comment, I now lean towards a div. But it really doesn't matter.

Comment: One reason I was leaning towards a form was that inside a form you usually have <label> and <input>. To me this makes more sense than having divs and p tags. The other option for associating items in this way is the definition list (dl,dd,dt), but I'm not really a fan of that because on each pair their is no way to add a wrapping element. Typically I have a form, with an ul, and inside each li I put a label and an input. I was using that setup here and a friend was arguing against the form b/c it did not submit data. I guess either way is ok - thank you all for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Purely from an accessibility standpoint, whithout knowing how you want to implement this, It sounds as if the Language Select and Timezone Select functions require the customer to pick from a list. For these, I invision two, small, forms. Each form would contain a label tag that uses the for attribute. Those forms would also have a list input tag. Finally, they 
would have a submit button. You would give the input tags name attributes. You would paste the values of the name attributes into the for attribute strings for the label tags.

I invision the other two items possibly as small forms with just buttons that would fire functions. They could also be hyperlinks, but best practices in accessibility might dictate that they not be hyperlinks, just in case someone uses a browser that doesn't support scripting, or for whatever reason, someone has scripting turned off.